# How to use properties file from a nested folder inside /src/main/resources?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application where I want to externalize the messages. I am categorizing these messages into errors, info, and success. Thus I'm creating a nested folder structure as below:

[image]

And, I'm trying to access this from the service in the following manner:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en");
ResourceBundle errors = ResourceBundle.getBundle("errors", locale); 
System.out.println(errors.getString("E000"));
```

This gives me the following exception:

> java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name errors, locale en

However, if I keep the properties file outside the folders as below, it works fine:

[image]

So,

1. How do I make sure that the ResourceBundle is able to find the property file located inside the nested folder?
2. Can it be done without updating the classpath?
3. Is this an apt way to manage messages of the application? Or are there still better ways to externalize and manage these error, info and success messages?

Comment: Why can't you just do this: `ResourceBundle errors = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages/errors/errors", locale); `?

Comment: Wy are you using a `ResourceBundle` instead of letting Spring load that file by configuring the `spring.messages.basenames=messages,errors/errors`. This way Spring will create an `MessageSource` which you can use to achieve the same.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm actually totally new to this. Can you please help me out with some references? I'll try implementing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below will work: as resources is your class path so you need to pass messages also..if you will move out errors file from messages to classpath so it works as by default classpath is resources..

```
ResourceBundle errors = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages/errors/errors", locale);
```

Comment: Tried implementing this, got similar error: Can't find bundle for base name messages/errors, locale en.

Comment: Now it does work. However, my structure is messages/errors/errors. So I moved it inside the error folder. Thanks!

Comment: @MrudavShukla out of curiosity... how is this different from the code I posted in my comment (below the question post)??

Comment: @lealceldeiro Yup. It's exactly the same. That's why I marked your comment as helpful and deleted my comment as there was some other error due to which it didn't work at the first go. I deleted it to avoid confusions for fellow readers. Thanks :)